# Read .properties file to set value in use and password field in Expect shell script

Tags: shell, expect

How to read values from Properties file for user and Password field in expect in shell?

Suppose if i have values.prop file having values like below,

```
user=abcd
pwd=xxxx
```

I want to set the above value in my test.sh as below

```
!/usr/bin/expect
set user "abcd"
set password "xxxx"
spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "$user@$hosts's password:"
send "$password\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the format of the properties file then the easiest way would be to use the [`source` functionality of tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcltutorial/html/Tcl30.html) (expect script are practically tcl scripts).

```
!/usr/bin/expect
source values.prop
spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "$user@$hosts's password:"
send "$password\n"
```

With `values.prop` now looking like this:

```
set user "abcd"
set password "xxxx"
```

---

Here is a crude shell script which can automatically translate the properties file to a tcl file

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$1"
printf 'set user "%s"\n' "$user"
printf 'set password "%s"\n' "$password"
```

Use like this:

```
translate ./values.prop > values.prop.tcl
```

Then `source values.prop.tcl` in your expect script.

Comment: Thanks Lesmana!..Its Working Fine...But i tried without that translate crude shell also, it works fine..Just the Command Source is needed to read the file content set user "abcd"
set password "xxxx" in expect.